# Is there a combinatorial interpretation for the change of basis matrix in the Frobenius normal form representation?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, matrices, factorization

Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices. Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$ (i.e., rows and columns of $A$ are indexed by vertices of $G$, and the $(v,w)$ entry of $A$ is $1$ if $(v,w)$ is an edge in $G$ and zero otherwise).

Suppose for simplicity that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is equal to the minimal polynomial of $A$.

Let $A = UCU^{-1}$ be a [Frobenius normal form (or rational canonical form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form) representation of $A$ (so $C$ is the companion matrix of the characteristic polynomial of $A$).

The coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ have a natural combinatorial interpretation (they correspond to signed counts of collections of disjoint cycles in $G$ of a certain total size), so some of the entries of $C$ have a combinatorial interpretation.

**Question:** Is there a nice combinatorial interpretation for the entries of $U$ or $U^{-1}$? What about the matrix $AU = UC$?

Comment: Do you mean that $AU=UC$?

Comment: Good point, you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is some thoughts so far, not a complete answer. It might help to describe such $U$ combinatorially if we can at least systemically find $U$ in integer entries.
In addition to minimal=characteristic, let's assume that all vertices are connected to some edges. If not, we can remove vertices without any edges.

**1. Spectral theorem and Vandermonde**

The adjacency matrix $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable, say $A=XDX^{-1}$, $X$ is an orthogonal matrix, and $D$ is diagonal. Since the minimal polynomial coincides with the characteristic polynomial $p(x)$, the eigenvalues $\{\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n\}$ of $A$ are real and all distinct.

The transpose $C^T$ of the companion matrix (whose $1$'s are above the diagonal) satisfies $C^T=YDY^{-1}$ where $Y$ is Vandermonde matrix (whose row of all $1$'s at the top row). Then the usual companion matrix $C=Y^{-T} D Y^T$ (whose $1$'s are below the diagonal) where $Y^{-T}=(Y^{-1})^T$. This gives $D=Y^T C Y^{-T}$. Putting this into the diagonalization of $A$, we obtain $A=XY^T C (XY^T)^{-1}$. Thus, by taking $U=XY^T$, we have $A=UC U^{-1}$. Note that we have
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix} | & | & \cdots & | \\ {\bf v}_1 & {\bf v}_2 & \cdots & {\bf v}_n\\
| & | & \cdots & | \end{pmatrix}, Y^T=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \lambda_1 & \lambda_1^2 &\cdots & \lambda_1^{n-1}\\
1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_2^2 & \cdots & \lambda_2^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & \lambda_n & \lambda_n^2 & \cdots & \lambda_n^{n-1}\\\end{pmatrix},
$$
with $A{\bf v}_i=\lambda_i{\bf v}_i$, ${\bf v}_i\neq 0$. This $U$ might have non-integer entries, so it will be difficult to give a combinatorial meaning to the entries.

Since the minimal and characteristic polynomials are the same, the space of matrices $U$ with $AU=UC$ is $n$-dimensional. Thus, we see that any such a matrix $U$ can be written as
$$
U=X \ \text{Diag}(c_1, \ldots, c_n) \ Y^T
$$
with $c_i\in\mathbb{R}$. Among those, the invertible ones are with $c_i\neq 0$ for each $i$. Thus, the columns of $X \ \text{Diag}(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$ are nonzero eigenvectors of $A$. We search for $c_i$'s that make the above $U$ have integer entries.

**2. Adjugate matrix and eigenvectors**

We refer to the properties of the adjugate matrix given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

For any $x$,
$$
(xI -A) \text{adj}(xI -A)=p(x) I.
$$
If $x=\lambda$ is any eigenvalue of $A$, then $\text{rk}(\lambda I -A)=n-1$, $\text{rk}(\text{adj}(\lambda I -A))=1$ and
$$
\text{adj}(\lambda I -A)= \alpha {\bf x} {\bf y}^T
$$
where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, $A{\bf x}=\lambda {\bf x}$, and $A^T{\bf y}=\lambda {\bf y}$. Note again that $A^T=A$ here, then we may take
$$
\text{adj}(\lambda I -A)= \beta {\bf x} {\bf x}^T
$$ with $A{\bf x}=\lambda {\bf x}$, necessarily ${\bf x}\neq 0$ and $\beta\neq 0$.

For each eigenvalue $\lambda$, we have a nonzero column of
$\text{adj}(\lambda I -A)$, and it is an eigenvector. The problem is that the position of the nonzero column may differ for each eigenvalue. To make sure choosing a nonzero eigenvector systemically, we use the linear combination of columns with scalars $(1 \ R \ R^2 \ \cdots \ R^{n-1})$ for sufficiently large integer $R$. By Gershgorin's circle theorem, we have a bound for eigenvalue $|\lambda|\leq n-1$. Each coefficient in polynomial entries of $\text{adj}(xI -A)$ is bounded by $n!$. The degrees of entries of $\text{adj}(xI -A)$ is bounded by $n-1$. Thus, entries of $\text{adj}(\lambda I -A)$ is bounded by $n!n(n-1)^{n-1}$. The sum of all entries of $\text{adj}(\lambda I -A)$ is bounded by $n!n^3(n-1)^{n-1}$. For simplicity, we use $n^{2n+2}$. Let $b>0$ be the minimal absolute value of all nonzero entries of $\text{adj}(\lambda I -A)$ for all choice of $\lambda$. Then we choose $R>n^{2n+2}/b$. We can further find a lower bound of $b$ to take $R$ large depending only on $n$.

Suppose for an eigenvalue $\lambda=\beta_1$ of $A$, a nonzero entry $g(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of $\text{adj}(xI-A)$ gives the lowest positive absolute value. The degree of the polynomial $g(x)$ is at most $n-1$. Let $d$ be the degree of $\lambda$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $g(\lambda)$ is an algebraic integer. Also, $g(\beta_1),\ldots, g(\beta_d)$ are all algebraic integer for the complete list of conjugates $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_d$ of $\beta_1$. Then $g(\beta_1)\cdots g(\beta_d)$ must be a nonzero integer. Thus,
$$
|g(\beta_1)\cdots g(\beta_d)|\geq 1. 
$$
Then
$$
|g(\beta_1)|\geq 1/|g(\beta_2)\cdots g(\beta_d)|.
$$
The coefficients of $g$ are bounded by $n!$, each $\beta_i$ is bounded by $n-1$, yielding $|g(\beta_i)|\leq n!n(n-1)^{n-1}< n^{2n}$. Since $d\leq n$, we obtain
$$
b=|g(\beta_1)|> (1/n^{2n})^{n-1}.
$$
Hence, we may take $R= n^{2n+2} n^{2n(n-1)} = n^{2n^2+2}$.

Denote by ${\bf v}(x)=(f_1(x) \ \cdots \ f_n(x))^T$ the linear combination we obtain from $$\text{adj}(xI -A) (1 \ R \ R^2 \ \cdots \ R^{n-1})^T.$$ The polynomials $f_j$ have integer entries. We take $c_i{\bf v}_i={\bf v}(\lambda_i)$ for each $i=1,\ldots, n$. Then
$$
U=X \ \text{Diag}(c_1, \ldots, c_n) \ Y^T$$
$$
=\begin{pmatrix} | & | & \cdots & | \\ {\bf v}(\lambda_1) & {\bf v}(\lambda_2) & \cdots & {\bf v}(\lambda_n)\\
| & | & \cdots & | \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \lambda_1 & \lambda_1^2 &\cdots & \lambda_1^{n-1}\\
1 & \lambda_2 & \lambda_2^2 & \cdots & \lambda_2^{n-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
1 & \lambda_n & \lambda_n^2 & \cdots & \lambda_n^{n-1}\\\end{pmatrix}
$$
has integer entries and is invertible. This is because the above $U$ involves integer coefficients and $\text{tr}(A^j)=\lambda_1^j + \cdots + \lambda_n^j$.